# Audio File Bloat in Adobe Flash CS4

Tags: flash, audio, flash-cs4, media, filesize

Whenever I import an MP3 into Flash CS4, I see massive file size increases within the FLA. Not only does the file size of the MP3 in the Library bloat, but the file size and export time of the FLA increase dramatically as well. This leads to all sorts of memory errors and slow performance.

MP3 File in Windows Explorer:

[alt text http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/5937/snag0003.jpg](http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/5937/snag0003.jpg)

MP3 File in Flash CS4 Library

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9393/snag0004d.jpg](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9393/snag0004d.jpg)

Notice that the file size went from 1.92 MB to 22.2 MB upon import. The size of the FLA went from 32 KB (blank) to 21.9 MB.

I've tried saving in a variety of formats -- WAV, MP3, ASND, etc and having no luck. Ideally, I would like to export something from SoundBooth (or QuickTime Pro, After Effects, Premiere) that does not need increase FLA size or export time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're instantiating the sound with code you can just use embed metadata to do the trick. It works like this (all code assumed to be in a class):

```
[Embed(source = 'loop.mp3')]
private var MusicClass:Class;
private var music:Sound = new MusicClass();
```

Then just instantiate music and off you go!

This doesn't affect the FLA at all or make compile time that much longer.

Note that you'll have to have the Flex SDK (which is free) installed somewhere on your machine to use this. Flash will prompt you for it's location the first time you compile.

Comment: And this compiles the MP3 into the SWF?

Comment: Yes it does...just figured that out. Thanks!